# A really small custom Javascript alert/dialog library without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know of any tiny Javascript library for creating custom HTML styled alert box?

Anytime I try to search for it online, I only get tons of jQuery plugins.

I want a pure JS library, or it can be [Minified.js](http://minifiedjs.com)...but no jQuery, jQuery bad!

Comment: Too big for my needs.

Comment: http://www.cssscript.com/small-javascript-alert-confirm-dialog-replacement-custom-alert/

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Thank you so much @Pete

Comment: [UPDATE]Petes comment looks better ;)[/UPDATE]
http://www.naden.de/blog/javascript-alert is a small library which rewrappes the native alert function with header texts, callbacks and so on. It is documented in german only, but not hard to figure out though. check the demos: http://www.naden.de/blog/wp-content/download/javascript-alert-demo.html

Comment: @mondjunge hmm...that is interesting :D I think, I'll try this first

Comment: hi now used to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/z0p8gfa9/

Comment: Okay I recently made one in TypeScript and it compiled down to pure js. 5kb minified. Absolutely no dependencies. It's on my github - https://github.com/binarybaba/prophetjs
I've some gifs on the readme to see how it looks. Cheeres!

Answer (score 3):

Why not to Create a simple div that inside you will have buttons that will act like an alert Box.

And then in a simple javascript you can control this div .

In that way you dont need any library .

Thanks

Comment: try this :

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial

simple tutorial and you can copy the example :)